# In google script run from a google site, I am getting a Macro missing argument message

Tags: google-apps-script

The following is giving me a `Macro missing argument error` and I cannot seem to understand why.  I am attempting to get the average of one column of a variable length set of rows, if three other columns in those rows meet three criteria.  Thoughts?

```
function respondToSubmit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetkey"); 
    var ss1= ss.getSheetByName('AllLive');
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var year = app.getElementById('year');
    var selectedyear = e.parameter.year; 
    var quarterlist = app.getElementById('quarterlist');
    var selectedquarter = e.parameter.quarterlist; 
    var data = ss1.getDataRange().getValues();

    for(nn=1;nn<data.length;++nn){     
        var sheetyear = data[nn][12];
        var sheetquarter = data[nn][13];
        var lengthofimp = data[nn][10];  
        var live = data[nn][9];  

        if (selectedyear == sheetyear && selectedquarter == sheetquarter && live =="LIVE"){
            var avlenghthimp = lengthofimp;
            var answer = app.createLabel(avlenghthimp);
            app.add(answer);
            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error say which line?  Guessing it's on your Average().  You're only giving it 1 value.  I'd throw some logs in between variables to look further.

Comment: Ya, nothing to do with my "Average()".  I edited the code.  Basically, I do not know what you mean by "throw some logs in between variables"?

Comment: You can use Logger.log() or the Debug icon to help see the values.  Please look into those 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written a function called `Average` ? If not, it won't work. 
So, write the average function yourself.

Comment: Sorry about that, the Average function, does, in fact, not exist.  It was a way to place hold what I wanted to do with the returned values.  I have done a similar kind of solution before, but in that one, there was always just ONE value that met a certain criteria.  How does one pull multiple?  I have edited the code... it still says that I am missing an argument and returns "undefined".